# How to turn a disorganized text file into an Array[String] in Scala?

Tags: scala, split, text-files

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
 10 10 
 54 129 155 559 10.00 10.00 
 99999 3 15 15 15 15 15 15 
 15 15 
 120 195 258 744 10.00 10.00 
 3 99999 15 15 15 15 15 15 
 15 15
```

amount of ints/doubles per line can vary.

I can't read line by line because the amount on them are not constant. I've been trying with split, mkString and such to no success.

```scala
val lines = Source.fromFile(s"/tmp/$filepath")
                  .getLines.mkString
                  .split("\n").mkString
                  .split(" ").map(_.trim)
```

When I try to read it like:

```scala
lines(0).toInt
```

It return: [NumberFormatException: For input string: ""]

Need that to look like this:

A = Array('10', '10', '54', '129', '155', '559', '10.00', '10.00', '99999', '3', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '120', '195', '258', '744', '10.00', '10.00', '3', '99999', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15', '15')

Comment: On the edit: note that '10.00' won't parse as integer, even though it has `.00` after the floating point.

Comment: I treat every data as needed, some files can be 1.23 for examples, this is not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you wanted with all those `mkString`s there... Anyway, this here works just fine:

```
io.Source.fromFile("input.txt").getLines.flatMap(_.trim.split(" +")).toArray
```